# Javascript click event in for loop not working?

Tags: javascript

```
function albumCoverDisplay() {

  var i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < albumCover.length; i++) {

    albumCover[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

      for (var i = 0; i < albumCover.length; i++) {

        albumInfo[i].style.display = "none";

      }

      albumInfo[i].style.display = "block";

    });

  }

}
```

Comment: What is it doing? Does it only hide the last one? or do nothing at all? Do you have any console errors?

Comment: Would would be the intention of your double for loop? The outer loop can define `i` as `let`, the inner one needs to use a different indexer to hide all previous items

Comment: Please add a description of what you want it to do. And what it actually does. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I basically have a site with album covers (albumCover) and when clicked its supposed to display the list of songs in the album (albumInfo) and hide the other list which appeared after chicking on any previous album covers

Comment: you are declaring 2 times `i`

Comment: Oh thanks a lot @useles'MJ that was the problem. Im new to JS so didn't really think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to be able to hide other *albumCover elements* on clicking one of them.

There are a couple of mistakes

- **Your inner for-loop re-localize the scope of `i`**, use different variable
- i's value (assuming another variable is used in inner for-loop) will not remain same when the click will happen.

Make it

```
function albumCoverDisplay() 
{
  for (let i = 0; i < albumCover.length; i++)  //use let instead of var
  { 
    albumCover[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      for (var j = 0; j < albumCover.length; j++) 
      {
          albumInfo[j].style.display = "none";
      }
      albumInfo[i].style.display = "block";
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea thanks buddy that fixed it. Not only as @useless'MJ mentioned I had declared "i" twice but also as you showed didn't have var or let in the first loop I declaration. Thanks a lot